# Split string by char, but skip certain char combinations

Tags: c#, javascript, string, split

Say I have a string in a form similar to this:

`"First/Second//Third/Fourth"` (notice the double slash between `Second` and `Third`)

I want to be able to split this string into the following substrings `"First", "Second//Third", "Fourth"`. Basically, what I want is to split the string by a char (in this case `/`), but not by double of that char (in this case `//`). I though of this in a number of ways, but couldn't get it working.

I can use a solution in C# and/or JavaScript.

Thanks!

Edit: I would like a simple solution. I have already thought of parsing the string char by char, but that is too complicated in my real live usage.

Comment: need to write custom logic , i don't think there is inbuilt mechanism to it AFAIK

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try with this C# solution, it uses positive lookbehind and positive lookahead:

```
        string s = @"First/Second//Third/Fourth";
        var values = Regex.Split(s, @"(?<=[^/])/(?=[^/])", RegexOptions.None);
```

It says: delimiter is `/` which is preceded by any character except `/` and followed by any character except `/`.

Here is another, shorter, version that uses negative lookbehind and lookahead:

```
        var values = Regex.Split(s, @"(?<!/)/(?!/)", RegexOptions.None);
```

This says: delimiter is `/` which is not preceded by `/` and not followed by `/`

You can find out more about 'lookarounds' **[here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)**.

Comment: Thanks! It works great! Will mark your answer when the option will be available.

Comment: I'm not sure how you want to handle it, but the use of _positive_ lookaround here means that this _won't_ split on a slash at the _start or end_ of the input. (Since it's looking for "next to two non-slashes" rather than "not next to a slash".)

Comment: @Rawling I added the version with negative lookaround, except for what you said, negative lookaround version is shorter and, in my opinion, more readable.

Comment: Could you explain why < is needed for the lookahead but not for the lookbehind?

Comment: @zer0ne `<` is used to denote lookbehind, it's a syntax symbol that makes it clear that this pattern is actually negative lookbehind, without it, syntax would be the same as for positive lookahead.

Answer (score 5):

In .NET Regex you can do it with negative assertions.`(?<!/)/(?!/)` will work. Use `Regex.Split` method.

Answer (score 3):

ok one thing you can do is to split the string based on `/`. The array you get back will contain empty allocations for all the places `//` were used. loop through the array and concatenate `i-1` and `i+1` allocations where `i` is the pointer to the empty allocation.

Comment: Good solution if RegEx is not an option. I will use Ivan G's answer. Upvoted yours too.

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
var array = "First/Second//Third/Fourth".replace("//", "%%").split("/");

array.forEach(function(element, index) {
    array[index] = element.replace("%%", "//");
});
```

Comment: I thought of that, but the strings (First, Second etc) can also use "%%". I could end up with unwanted strings in my end results. Thanks for the idea, though!

Comment: Then use a string that is very, very unlikely to appear.