# Regular expression for string between quotes

Tags: c#, regex, string

[Scenario same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15108728/split-string-by-char-but-skip-certain-char-combinations)

First of all I don't know anything about RegularExpressions.

I am trying to split a string separated with comma(`,`). In my scenario there is a string which is a single record having double quotes in it(`"smilu,varghese"`) I found the answer in the above link. But when I try to do the `RegularExpression` it is giving me a wrong array.

Text to split

```
One,two,Three,"Four,Five",six
```

I need the record to be split like

```
One
two
three
Four,Five
six
```

The regular expression I am using

```
string[] lineArray = Regex.Split(line, @"(?<=[^""]),(?=[^""])", RegexOptions.None);
```

I know the above code is wrong and it is giving me a random split on the string.
Can anyone tell me how to write this regular expression for keeping the string between quotes(") in a single string?

Comment: I agree it is difficult to find the right SO post for this task, there are so many poorly answered and god-knows-why accepted questions. I think the one I linked to is helpful enough.

Comment: Let me check that link.

Comment: That worked perfectly. Thanks a lot